# Searchable text captions on a 3D model

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, modeling

Already considered asking this question on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com, but it's more programming than design related.

I have a 3D model, which has to come with a large number of text captions on it (50,000 of small captions).

If we place the captions on the 3D model as graphics, there's no way to search them (the goal is being able to zoom in to specific caption).

Is there a tool or technology that would allow to make them searchable so we could find the caption by its text and get its coordinates?

Obviously, we could manually save 3D coordinates for each caption, but that's not reasonable given the large number of them.

And if it's not possible with a raw 3D model, maybe Unity3D has a tool to allow that?

Comment: "... come with a large number of captions on it" - if it already comes with the text, then why would it not be searchable? Also "on it" suggests you already have the 3D coordinate for each caption, so why would you need to *manually* save? Unless you mean that the captions are actually in mesh geometry form and you need to *detect* them?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog the captions are given as an Excel spreadsheet. I can place them as textures on 3D model, but they won't be searchable. The question is how to locate them on 3D model programmatically.

Comment: Why cant you just store the textures *together* with the caption text? Do you need to dynamically update them?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog of course I can store them in memory, but the point is finding specific point on 3D model where the caption is placed. User inputs the text to search, and the game locates it on the model.

Comment: Wouldn't it then be trivial, if you can store them in memory? Just use a hash table or map (or any other structure that allows you to search text)

Comment: But where will we get the text coordinates on surface of 3D model? Unless you manually track 50000 captions and save their coordinates to hash table. Not realistic.

Comment: How would that be unrealistic if you could just use e.g. a loop? I just don't understand where your perceived problem comes from.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog it's not a matter of searching the hash table (or different structure), it's a matter of locating the captions on the surface of 3D model. I can copy&paste 50k captions to graphics editing software and save them as textures for 3D model, but they won't be searchable. And it's not possible to record coordinates for 50k captions manually. Does that make sense?

Comment: OK I think I see what your problem is now. Pretty sure Unity / C# Mono has functionality to render text to a graphics buffer? (C# .NET certainly does); then you can render them as e.g. sprites / billboards.